# Validation error on modify slug with date

Tags: python, django, wagtail

i'm trying to modify the slug on save to add a date at the end of it if the same slug already exists. Here is the code that i got:

```
import datetime as dt


class BlogPage(...):
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        now = dt.datetime.now()
        if self.slug:
            self.slug = f"{self.slug}-{now.isoformat()}"
        super().save(self, **kwargs)
```

Once i try to save i get a Validation error:

```
{'slug': ['Enter a valid “slug” consisting of Unicode letters, numbers, underscores, or hyphens.']}
```

Thank you

Comment: isoformat() contains `:` i think  thats why it is giving error

Answer (score 3):

ISO format consist colons and dots which are not supported by slugfield.
Use another format:

```
class BlogPage(...):
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    if self.slug:
        self.slug = f"{self.slug}-{now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%I-%S')}"
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Now i get an error `save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`